# Invalid indicated return type of generic arrow function passed as argument of the function

Tags: typescript

The return type of the generic arrow function passed as an argument is not properly indicated. I would expect it to throw an error e.g `test is not props of Page interface` in place of call **updater** function due to the fact that return type of the arrow function is not the expected one. In my case Page which have been passed as generic which does not contain test property.

```
export class Test<T> {
  updater<T>(updatefn: (state: T, value: any) => T): null {
    return null;
  };
}

interface Page {
    page: number;
}

const state = {
    page: 1
};

const value = 2;

const store = new Test<Page>();
store.updater((state, value) => ({page: 2, test:1}));
```

[CODE](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4BVhpgHiwD44BvAKDjgFcwATFGYKQogCloaYDMA7ALjhs8jYIKwAaOADcUSamLgpeATwCUcALwksawb2pIkZSlThRgMalF5wDRgNymAvk%20flyAS15Mo3FAjAcAAKKADmQRRmcGDhigYAtgBGzG4eCBC8eHAiTFom0bERggCM5K7pmdmy8kGacABMTuQZWfB40HV2wADu2LgEoRHsak4dFgB0nKJQbMIwolI1ChraQqRFig1STHj8Jc5qo0A)

Comment: Please include any example code as text in the question post so that the issue is clearly spelled out without requiring people to follow a link (see [ask]).  Also, that code seems to have syntax errors unrelated to the text of your question.  Could you please make sure it is demonstrating what you intend to demonstrate?  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks I have made some mistake in the example code, already fixed. Let me know if something else is not clear in the question.

Comment: thanks. It's the same issue as in the question this duplicates.  Please read that answer and let me know if you have any outstanding questions.  Good luck.

Comment: Thank you it's seems to be exactly my problem. What's more I really want to thank you for the job you are doing on stackoverflow. I have found a ton of your answer and all of them are so helpful. Everything you do is inspiring for me.